# Statistics, MLE and moments in Pareto distribution

Tags: statistics

I have an issue with my classwork problem. I keep getting stuck on the part where I have to find the expectation because of the $(\lambda+x)$ and this is why I can't find neither the moments estimator nor the MLE. Any help is much appreciated. Cheers in advance. 
[image]

Comment: 2.  The wealth of Mexico is well modeled by a Pareto(α,λ) distribution,
f(x) = αλα(λ+x) −α−1  , for x >0, α >1 and λ >0.
(a)  Assuming λ known:
i.  Find the method of moments estimator for α .
ii.  Find the mle for α.
(b)  Now assuming α known:
i.  Find the method of moments estimator for λ.
ii.  Find  the  mle  for λ.

Comment: That is the question, didn't get uploaded earlier...